# Setting up multi master MySQL cluster on different AWS regions

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, database-design, high-availability

I have a chat application that already has thousands of users. Servers are located in US(Oregon). Users are distributed across the globe. I have started facing an issue related to slow server response for users in India. I want to set up the same infra in India as well. The major problem is MySQL replication. A new MySQL master is created in India but Master-Master replication is creating problems as the database contains tables with auto-increment id as the primary key. As per my understanding, the following process is being followed

Let's assume auto-increment id is now 1000, time is XXXXXXX000 ms and latency between Oregon and Mumbai region is 200ms

> 1. At XXXXXXX000 ms, Server1(US) is adding a new row in xyz table, and now the auto-increment id is 1001.
> 2. At the same time XXXXXXX000 ms, Server2(Ind) is adding a new row in xyz table, and now the auto-increment id is 1001 on the same table.
> 3. After 200ms, Query executed on Server1(US) is replicated to Server2(Ind) which has auto-increment id as 1001 but failed to execute because the table already has that value.
> 4. Similarly, Query executed on Server2(Ind) is replicated to Server1(US) which has auto-increment id as 1001 but failed to execute because the table already has that value.

One of the solutions I found was to set auto_increment_increment and auto_increment_offset values on both the hosts as defined http://www.clusterdb.com/mysql-cluster/setting-up-mysql-asynchronous-replication-for-high-availability. 
I was able to replicate that but I am not sure whether this is the right approach for a production setup on AWS EC2. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: auto_increment_{increment|offset} solves one of the multimaster problems.

Comment: Intra-India latency can be improved, but latency between US and India cannot be improved -- can't beat the speed of light.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you found on [http://www.clusterdb.com/mysql-cluster/setting-up-mysql-asynchronous-replication-for-high-availability][1] is the right approach to use on production server.

Server 1 :

auto_increment_increment=2

auto_increment_offset=1

Server 2:

auto_increment_increment=2

auto_increment_offset=2

Comment: WRONG!  `auto_increment_increment` needs to be **2** on both servers.